# How to search a multidimensional associative array php

Tags: php, arrays, function, class, php-7

With api I get a multidimensional array php. I want to extract data from it with a simple code php.
I extract data from an array this way:

```
var_dump ($obj['product']);



echo $prise = ($obj['product']['return']['ProductsItem']['0']['Article']);

echo $Brand = ($obj['product']['return']['ProductsItem']['0']['Brand']);

echo $Currency = ($obj['product']['return']['ProductsItem']['0']['Currency']);

echo $Name = ($obj['product']['return']['ProductsItem']['0']['Name']);

echo $StockItem = ($obj['product']['return']['ProductsItem']['0']['Stock']['StockItem']['0']['Price']);

echo $StockItem = ($obj['product']['return']['ProductsItem']['0']['Stock']['StockItem']['0']['TransferTime']);


echo $StockItem1 = ($obj['product']['return']['ProductsItem']['0']['Stock']['StockItem']['0']['Count']);

echo $StockItem2 = ($obj['product']['return']['ProductsItem']['0']['Stock']['StockItem']['1']['Count']);
```

How do I simplify the code? How can the data in the array change?

Comment: Pretty unclear what you're asking, please clarify. If there are multiple items, shouldn't there be a loop somewhere?

Comment: I want to reflect this through a forech. But I don't know how?

Comment: It looks like you want something like this: https://3v4l.org/jSbfG

Comment: Thank you! 3v4l.org/jSbfG – Nick

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

foreach ($obj['product']['return']['ProductsItem'] as $productsitem) {
    $article = $productsitem['Article'];
    $brand = $productsitem['Brand'];
    $currency = $productsitem['Currency'];
    $name = $productsitem['Name'];
    foreach ($productsitem['Stock']['StockItem'] as $stockitem) {
        $price = $stockitem['Price'];
        $transfertime = $stockitem['TransferTime'];
        $count = $stockitem['Count'];
    }
}
```